# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and SELECT FOUND_ROWS() on UNION query (not UNION ALL) with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the total number of rows that would have been returned if there was no global LIMIT set. Here's what my query looks like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table1 WHERE [...]
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE [...]
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE [...]
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE [...]
LIMIT 0,30
```

Then I immediately follow that with the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` query. It returns a total of 35 rows, but it should return a total of 400 rows.  Any idea how I can count the rows WITHOUT using UNION ALL?

Comment: the calc_found_rows works on a per-query basis which breaks when you're doing a union. That's actually two queries being combined into one, and you'd only get the found rows for the LAST query executed in the union, not the entire union.

Comment: So is there any way to accomplish a row count on this kind of a query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use temporary table for all union selects:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [...]
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE [...]
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE [...]
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE [...]
)  temp_table
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Thank you! The answer was so brilliantly simple, thank you for your help!